# firefox download attribute not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, firefox, download

there is a link, I get it with the youtube, video download (asp.net mvc app)
to sign the `<a>` download- attribute and after the click starts downloading videos in all browsers except firefox.

```
<a href="http://r2---sn-gvnuxaxjvh-3bqe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?source=youtube&initcwndbps=1915000&key=yt6&itag=18&mime=video/mp4&sparams=dur,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&lmt=1458204157747766&ipbits=0&mt=1461327979&upn=P-BPZtDvYCs&mv=m&ms=au&signature=9BCA76565C6D54E5B334B2CEEF0BAC9BEABAF56C.187F3789494F93F1C15CEEF8811FBD0D5D6EDFCA&id=o-ALh1vb0zYplgUJjfSobe88IKV8G-Ul03nysjWF5JPccs&fexp=9406001,9407473,9416126,9416891,9422596,9425619,9426927,9428398,9429052,9429160,9429709,9431012,9431449,9432372,9433045,9433096,9433118,9433425,9433841,9433947,9434304,9434320&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&mm=31&ip=95.52.72.117&mn=sn-gvnuxaxjvh-3bqe&dur=191.843&pl=18&expire=1461349756" download="@Model.Title">Скачать видео</a>
```

Please help me, I tried many ways((( nothing works((

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox download is only respected for URLs that are same-origin. Mozilla [bug 923415](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923415) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download).

Answer (score 2):

FireFox disallow donwload from another domain.
You can write link to you domain and there, in backend, proxy to another domain.

Besides Safari don`t support this attribute - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=download)